# Commutants of commutative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

Let $W$ be a unital algebra and let $V$ be its maximal abelian subalgebra. Must the commutant $V^\prime$ of $V$ be commutative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is abelian then $V \subseteq V'$ by definition of the commutant.

If $V$ is *maximal* abelian, then I claim that this is an equality: $V = V'$. Indeed, suppose that $v \in V'$. Then the set $V \cup \{v\}$ consists of pairwise commuting elements and therefore generates an abelian subalgebra of $W$. This abelian subalgebra contains $V$, so it must be equal to $V$ by maximality. So it must be the case that $v \in V$.

In particular, yes, $V'$ is commutative.

(As another exercise, you may wish to prove that $V = V'$ if and only if $V$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra, without even assuming that the subset $V \subseteq W$ is a subalgebra!)

Comment: This is certainly correct, but for @belmondo’s benefit, I would’ve liked to see an explanation of how maximality comes into the argument.

Comment: @Lubin, you're absolutely right, and I've included more explanation.  (It was late when I first wrote my answer, so I was feeling short on words.)